# Gradle creates larger file than Jar

Tags: java, scala, gradle, build

I'm working in a Java (1.8)/Scala (2.10) mixed project which is being built via Gradle (2.13). The project also includes a number of resource files.

The problem is that the output jar file is much larger than I would expect at 16MB. Using the Jar tool, I expanded the file. I recreated the jar both with compression and compression disabled. The sizes of the file were 8.6MB and 18MB respectively.

The project is not using any of the compression properties that were added in 2.13. I had the same results with 2.7 and 2.8 as well. What is Gradle doing and how can I get it to use the good compression already available when creating Jar files?

edit:
This is not a fat jar.

Comment: Two questions for you: 1. why do you care? and 2. you do know that you can just run command line jar from a gradle task, don't you?

Comment: I care because, why would I pass around a larger Jar file than necessary? Between artifact management and it being used in a cloud computing environment, this file ends up getting copied several dozen times. Reducing the size by half would be a big difference.  I know that I can run Jar via command line but I assumed that's what the gradle task does anyway... doesn't it?

Comment: No, I don't think it does that. And, even if it did, apparently, it must be passing different parameters to it. 18M is peanuts either way ... For a fat jar I mean.